# Is there any library or native syntax could return a new object with key of an array and value of a callback function?

Tags: typescript

I want to do some function xxx like below

```
const source = ['a','b','c']

const result = source.xxx(key => key + 'hello')

//  or 

const result  = xxx(source,() => key => key + 'hello')

console.log(result)

// result
{
 'a': 'ahello',
 'b': 'bhello',
 'c': 'chello'
}
```

I know I could write code like below to get it

```
const source = ['a','b','c']

const xxx = (source: any[],callback) => {
 let result = {}
 source?.forEach(key => result = Object.assign({},result,{key: callback(key)})
 return result
}

const result = xxx(source,(key) => key + 'hello')
```

but is there any library or native syntax could do that without writing it on my own?

Comment: The "any library" part of this question is off-topic for SO. Library recommendations are specifically called out as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) which will create an object using a pairs of key and values. In TypeScript terms, it takes or `Iterable<[string | number | symbol, any]>`.

Combined with [default parameter values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters) you can very simply express the function like this:

```js
const xxx = (source = []) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    source.map(key => [key, `${key}hello`])
  );
}

console.log(xxx(["a", "b", "c"]));
console.log(xxx());
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgmBeGAKCICuAnYBTALhgEMwBPAbQF1kZqBKZAPhgG8AoGGbPKHMGAHkARgCs8wKADoAZthABbAKJgo2AJZ4IqTlxgYc+KQuIAHVAGs8ZZnStkANDAAGAElb2AvgAs8AGz8QZyp6XXoAbnZPdnZQSBA-PClAgHNUBDhUCgAiYmynbOF8mGzgbJCI2PAMROSQNIzUegigA)

However, since `.map()` involves creating a whole new array just to be consumed and discarded immediately, you can use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) (see also [this chapter](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/generators) in the *TypeScript Deep Dive* online book)

```
type Mapping<T, U> = (x: T) => U;

function* toEntries<T, Key, Value>(
    keyMapper: Mapping<T, Key>, 
    valueMapper: Mapping<T, Value>, 
    data: Iterable<T>
): Generator<[Key, Value]> {
    for (const item of data) {
        yield [keyMapper(item), valueMapper(item)];
    }
}
```

This will cut out the middleman and just supply key-value pairs as needed, without needing to do it all at once and wrapping them in an array.

With this, the call to create a new object becomes

```typescript
const xxx = (source: any[] = []) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    toEntries(x => x, x => `${x}hello`, source)
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmMBLAdgcwDwBUA0UCqAfFALxQAUAHgFxRYCUpx+A3AFBsBmArigMbAkAexQAqKMCEBRFMABOSCAGdseANIQQeAGpwANtwiFyAa03xEEObQvJ0qqBpCE8AN32HbVmwjuZcULoGRngAJnDAcLQAksBWcABGehDYhPS0AOIQKPGSchgA2k46HhAAusQA3mwAkJxCchR8IkrAUEhxALZQQpxQ4ZGM1TU1IIp6oVAFZiBecuQdEJ30bqVzC130Zew1AL5s+2zNKK1QlOekFEpC3HJ8ELRwKCAFZZevjCRVbFBQchDAW4oKAAeQSACsIAIAHScORCToyeSKJTkH6-CTSWQKZRUJhnPCUfEAAwAJJVKLsABYQPR6ITEvDXW73ejo+jsQ5HFpCZLQ+loKjncgFABEcFFeFFCUlUFFfFFZXoHLYQA)

```js
function* toEntries(keyMapper, valueMapper, data){
    for (const item of data) {
        yield [keyMapper(item), valueMapper(item)];
    }
}

const xxx = (source) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    toEntries(x => x, x => `${x}hello`, source)
  );
}


console.log(xxx(["a", "b", "c"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the JavaScript standard library that does what you're asking, but you can get there in various ways. From an *expressiveness* perspective, I like `map` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const xxx = (source) => Object.fromEntries(
    source.map(key => [key, `${key}hello`])
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const xxx = (source) => Object.fromEntries(
    source.map(key => [key, `${key}hello`])
);

const source = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(xxx(source));
```

That does involve some intermediate arrays and such.

I also like [VLAZ's approach using a generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401229/157247).

The simplest way would be a loop:

```
const xxx = (source) => {
    const result = {};
    for (const key of source) {
        result[key] = `${key}hello`;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const xxx = (source) => {
    const result = {};
    for (const key of source) {
        result[key] = `${key}hello`;
    }
    return result;
};

const source = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(xxx(source));
```

Some people would shoehorn that into a `reduce`, but it doesn't buy you anything:

```
const xxx = (source) => source.reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = `${key}hello`;
    return result;
}, {});
```

Live Example:

```js
const xxx = (source) => source.reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = `${key}hello`;
    return result;
}, {});

const source = ['a','b','c'];
console.log(xxx(source));
```

Comment: An alternative to the `.map()` that avoids the intermediate arrays is to use a generator function. Might be an overkill in many cases but it's still an option. [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/BmxxGm)

Comment: @VLAZ - Oooh, nice!! *(Perhaps post as an answer? It's a great approach.)* Of course, in theory that involves creating result objects, but maybe the JavaScript engine can optimize them away if you don't use them explicitly...

Comment: Yes, it will create a lot of result objects but at least not a whole array at once that will also be turned into objects. Hopefully engines are smart enough to optimise this further.