# is it possible to use .map() to create an object from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Here is a representative sample of data from a larger dataset in a project:

```
const data = [
                { scenario: '328', buckets: 2 },
                { scenario: '746', buckets: 1 },
                { scenario: '465', buckets: 2 }
            ];
```

There is a need to reformat the data into an object with the scenario value as the key and the bucket value as the value, like this:
[image]

I have been able to achieve this outcome by using `.forEach` like so:

```
const reformattedData = {};
            data.forEach(o => {
                reformattedData[o.scenario] = o.buckets;
            });
```

but I suspect there is a more concise way to accomplish the same output.  I have tried `.map` as follows

```
const reformattedData = data.map(o => ({ [o.scenario] : o.buckets}));
```

but it doesn't give the intended output.  Instead it gives `[{328: 2}, {746: 1}, {465: 2}]`.  What needs to be modified in the `.map()` version to attain the desired output?

Comment: Looks like you need `Array.reduce`

Comment: I advise against using `.map()` for trivial iteration. At best, you can create an array of key-value pairs and then use `Object.fromEntries()` (you can [use a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401229/) to map into key-value pairs to feed into `fromEntries` if you want) but a `.forEach()` (or a normal loop) is more straight forward. You can also `.reduce()` into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the data and create an object from the entries with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const
    data = [{ scenario: '328', buckets: 2 }, { scenario: '746', buckets: 1 }, { scenario: '465', buckets: 2 }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ scenario, buckets }) =>
        [scenario, buckets]
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Another solution by spreading objects for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const
    data = [{ scenario: '328', buckets: 2 }, { scenario: '746', buckets: 1 }, { scenario: '465', buckets: 2 }],
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...data.map(({ scenario, buckets }) => ({ [scenario]: buckets }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Was just going to add this as second solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
const data = [
   { scenario: '328', buckets: 2 },
   { scenario: '746', buckets: 1 },
   { scenario: '465', buckets: 2 }
];
const res = data.reduce((ac, {scenario:s, buckets:b}) => ({...ac, [s]:b}), {});
console.log(res)
```