# Filter list of objects based on property of objects in another list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sorting

I have a list of objects:

```
let data = [{... , user: "user 1"}, {... , user: "user 1"}, {... , user: "user 1"}, {... , user: "user 2"}, {... , user: "user 2"}]
```

I have another list containing some objects, with information about the user and whether it is selected or not

```
let filter = [{user: "user 1", selected: true}, {user: "user 2", selected: false}]
```

How can I obtain another array containing just the objects in the first list that have a user property whose object in the filter list has selected property set to true?
An example of the results using the lists above would be

```
let data = [{... , user: "user 1"}, {... , user: "user 1"}, {... , user: "user 1"}]
```

Comment: _**Hint:**_  use `Array.filter()` method, With `Array.find()`

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object or a `Map` which maps each `user` to its `selected` property. Then `filter` the array using the map object:

```js
const filterMap = new Map(filter.map(o => [o.user, o.selected]))
const output = data.filter(d => filterMap.get(d.user))
```

Comment: Instead of a `.reduce()` it's also possible to directly use the map constructor `new Map(filter.map(o => [o.user, o.selected]))`. Since the map constructor also accepts an iterable [a generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64401229/) can avoid the intermediary array.